# Does tmux "sort" the PATH variable?

Tags: tmux

I have a reproducible problem:

1. set up my PATH in Bash .profile
2. start tmux by `tmux`, `tmux attach` or any variant
3. echo $PATH and see it with the same components but in different order

How to stop this? What explains it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you're on a Mac and have been wondering why `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` keeps getting prepended to PATH when you run tmux, it's because of a utility called path_helper that's run from your `/etc/profile` file.

You can't easily persuade tmux (or rather, bash) not to source `/etc/profile` (for some reason tmux always runs as a login shell, which means /etc/profile will be read), but you can make sure that the effects of path_helper don't screw with your PATH.

The trick is to make sure that PATH is empty before path_helper runs. In my `~/.bash_profile` file I have this:

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    PATH=""
    source /etc/profile
fi
```

Clearing PATH before path_helper executes will prevent it from prepending the default PATH to your (previously) chosen PATH, and will allow the rest of your personal bash setup scripts (commands further down `.bash_profile`, or in `.bashrc` if you've sourced it from `.bash_profile`) to setup your PATH accordingly.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: This totally did it for me! I have it hidden behind an `if [ -n "$TMUX" ]` clause myself, but I was wondering -- how important is the `[ -f /etc/profile ]`, really? Isn't it safe to assume that `/etc/profile` is always a regular file?

Comment: @RyanLue You could comfortably replace `-f` with `-e`, but I wouldn't personally try and source a file from a script that gets run when I login unless I'd checked it was there. I do tend to re-use my bash script on lots of different machines (and operating systems) though, so I like to make sure they're bullet proof. I can imagine some other unix variants might call it something else.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This was driving me crazy, and putting that little snippet at the top of my `~/.bash_profile` brought sanity back to my happy tmux world.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with system defaults, `set -g default-command "${SHELL}"` in `.tmux.conf` forces tmux to use non-login shells. I don't see the point in those anyway, since you usually open tmux after you've already logged in.

Comment: For zsh, your system may be using `/etc/zprofile` just a heads up to check

Comment: This fixed my setup, as well, after a couple days of trying to figure out how to get `tmux` not to source `/etc/profile`. FWIW no incantation of `set -g default-command ...` that I tried worked, including the one above from @seeker_of_bacon. I personally have `if [ -n "$TMUX" ] && [ -f /etc/profile ]` as I only want the path-resetting and sourcing of `/etc/profile` to happen in this specialized context.

Answer (score 6):

No; sorting `$PATH` would be a too crazy thing to do, since many systems depend on its user-set order.

However, tmux *does* start your shell in "login" mode, causing `~/.profile` to be sourced *again*. This means that if you have something like `PATH=/my/dir:/another/dir:$PATH` in that file, *it will be done again*, resulting in $PATH containing `/my/dir:/another/dir:/my/dir:/another/dir:(etc.)`. To avoid this, you could use another variable to check:

```
if [ "$_SKIP_PROFILE" ]; then
    return 0
else
    export _SKIP_PROFILE=y
fi

export PATH="/my/dir:/another/dir:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Graham Ashton Thanks for your idea

My suggestion would be that you put

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    PATH=""
    source /etc/profile
fi
```

at your .zshrc file at the top of it.

MAKE SURE that your

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

is below.